# "." and ".." file in Unix/Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I am new to Unix/Linux. When I use the following command,

```
$ ls
```

there are always two files like

```
. ..
```

What do they mean in Unix/Linux? Thank you.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2):

. is current dir and .. is parent dir.

.. Is particularly handy to use with cd